# get_term_by "name" not working with & in name

Tags: terms

I want to get category id by name so I am using [get_term_by](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

This is working fine when name is simple but when '&' is coming in term name it is not fetching category id.

e.g I have a term named "Website Development & Designing" under **skills** taxonomy and I am using following query to get its term id.

```
$value = "Website Development & Designing"
get_term_by('name',$value,'skills');
```

but it does not return term object :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters <, >, &, " and ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote and single quote) are enconded in term names. & becomes `&amp;`. This is done by passing the term object to `sanitize_term()` function which applies several filters. By default WordPress applies theses filters: `sanitize_text_field()`, `wp_filter_kses()` and `_wp_specialchars()` (see `wp-includes/default-filters.php`), this last function encondes <, >, &, " and '.

So, you need to do:

`$value = "Website Development &amp; Designing"
get_term_by('name',$value,'skills');`

Or, for unknown values:

`get_term_by( 'name', esc_attr( $value ), 'skills');`

NOTE: use `esc_attr()`, not `_wp_specialchars()` directly because [`_wp_specialchars()` is marked as private function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_specialchars) and it is not intended for use by plugin or theme developers.

Answer (score 1):

When you save special character in term, it is encoded as HTML entity.
So the term name in database will look like `Website Development &amp; Designing` and you are querying `Website Development & Designing`

You can use [`esc_attr()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) to encode the special characters before passing it as a argument.

```
$value = esc_attr( 'Website Development & Designing' );
get_term_by('name', $value, 'skills');
```

Better I will suggest you to query terms by slug always. The name can be changed anytime and you need to update the code every time.